# Is there a way to automatically remove non-consecutive duplicate words from a text?

Tags: text-editors

Is there a way to automatically remove **non-consecutive** (and consecutive) duplicate words from a text?

This is just a simple text. The end result should be a text in which every word 
(chunks of letters separated by space and/or punctuation marks, including the hyphen) occurs only once. So, I'm not interested in meaning, just word count and absence of recurrence.
Thank you.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: My OS is Win 10.

Comment: This website does it for you [Remove Duplicate Words and Repeated Keywords](https://www.tracemyip.org/tools/remove-duplicate-words-in-text/)